# Unable to configure Laravel storage symlink

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

Tired of searching :-(

**Configuration:**

- AWS (Instance)
- Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
- Laravel 5.8

Project root -> Permission and ownership
[image]

Inside project root

```
php artisan storage:link
```

*project/public*

[image]

**Browser console says:**

[image]

The complete project is working fine, even I am able to upload as follows.

```
$request->file('picture')->store('profile_pictures', 'public')
```

Comment: can you try clearing your view cache php artisan view:clear and php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

```
cd /var/www/html/yourproject
chmod -R 755 storage
chown -R www-data:www-data storage
```

Thanks.